# как найти элемент по id, используя input.value?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Я пробовал этот код но он не работает:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
var term = document.getElementById('input').value;
document.getElementById(term).style.display ='flex';
}
```

> Error: cannot read property 'style' of null.

Я ввожу правильный `id`.

Comment: value как может быть flex'ом ? value это значение а переменная term это value

Comment: Вы хотите в зависимости от значения value из input давать стили какому-то элементу?

Comment: я скрыл элементы и хочу раскрывать эти элементы по id. А id ввести в input. И по input.value искать по id и поменять их стиль

Comment: ну так вы же флекс придаёте value - а надо блоку/классу или сущности

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Раз в метках `jquery`, то вот моё решение задачи

```js
$('#search').on('input', function(){ // При вводе текста..
  $('.block.-active').removeClass('-active'); // убираем класс .-active у .block.-active
  
  if($('.block[id="'+$(this).val()+'"]').length > 0) { // проверяем если такой блок с таким id, если есть..
    $('.block[id="'+$(this).val()+'"]') // берём блок у которого есть совпадение по id
      .addClass('-active'); // выдаём ему класс .-active
  }
});
```

```css
.block {
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  background: gray;
  opacity: .5;
  padding: 0 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.block::before {
  content: attr(id);
  display: inline;
}

.block.-active {
  opacity: 1;
  background: green;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="search" type="text" value="">
<div class="block" id="one"></div>
<div class="block" id="good"></div>
<div class="block" id="sad"></div>
<div class="block" id="hover"></div>
<div class="block" id="click"></div>
<div class="block" id="lol"></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Я не мог справится с этим пол дня!

Answer (score 0):

Логика строится в том, чтобы добавить класс `.active` к элементу, который мы нашли

```js
const input = document.getElementById('input');
const elems = [...document.getElementsByClassName('elem')];
input.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
  const value = e.target.value; // value из input'a
  const newBlock = document.getElementById(value); // пытаемся получить элемент по value, который в input
  if (newBlock !== null) { // если мы получили элемент, то даём ему класс .active
    newBlock.classList.add('active');
  } else { // иначе проходимся циклом по elems и убираем у них класс .active
    elems.forEach((elem, i) => {
      elem.classList.remove('active');
    });
  }
});
```

```css
#input {
  display: block;
}

.elem {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
  opacity: 0.2;
  transition: opacity 0.2s linear;
}

.elem.active {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<input id="input" type="text">
<div class="elem" id="elem1">elem1</div>
<div class="elem" id="elem2">elem2</div>
<div class="elem" id="elem3">elem3</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Твой код читает инпут.value только один раз когда dom загружен полностью и jquery подключился(+0.1 сек от загрузки дома, не заморачивайся)

Определись, [jQuery](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%A1%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B) ты используешь или нативный js (`document.getElementById`)

Вот твой код без ожидания загрузки dom

```js
const term = $('input').val();
$(`#${term}`).css('display', 'flex');
```

Самый универсальный ожидатель загрузки дома, для меня:

```js
window.onload=()=>{
    // code
};
```

А вообще рекомендую два экстета: [этот](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/js-exec/caeimpdeapdimekjkkkggpibnlijlnka)(realtime) и [вотэтот](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/user-javascript-and-css/nbhcbdghjpllgmfilhnhkllmkecfmpld)(page refresh)